# Verify GPG file signature with Perl

Tags: perl, gnupg

I want to verify a GPG signed file (Verify archive.tar.gz with archive.tar.gz.sign).

ATM I simply call gpg directly and parse the exit code and output. While this is a works-for-me solution, I figure there must be a nicer way to do this in a more perlish way.

But as a programming novice I fail to understand how I can use the GPG CPAN modules.

Any hints are much appreciated!

Comment: What don't you understand?  How to download the CPAN module itself, or how to use it once it has been installed?  What have you tried?

Comment: I tried it with three different modules. With [GnuPG](http://search.cpan.org/~frajulac/GnuPG-0.09/) and the following code:  `use strict;
use warnings;
use GnuPG qw( :algo );

my $gpg = new GnuPG();

my $sig = $gpg->verify( signature => "linux-2.6.32.31.tar.bz2.sign", file => "linux-2.6.32.31.tar.bz" );`

Comment: ... and what does it do, and what do you expect it to do?  You keep basically saying "it doesn't work", which is not helpful.  It works lovely here.  It `croak`s if the signature verification fails; otherwise, you should print out the contents of your `$sig` hashref variable there.  (You should note, though, that in trying to find the identical kernel version, I noticed that kernel 2.6.32 only appeared to go up to 2.6.32.27...)

Answer (score 4):

The [GnuPG module](http://search.cpan.org/~frajulac/GnuPG-0.09/GnuPG.pm) on CPAN contains this in the synopsis:

```
use GnuPG qw( :algo );
my $gpg = new GnuPG();
$gpg->verify( signature => "file.txt.asc", file => "file.txt" );
```

It seems very clean.

Answer (score 0):

The [Crypt::OpenPGP](http://search.cpan.org/%7Esromanov/Crypt-OpenPGP-1.12/lib/Crypt/OpenPGP.pm) module may be of help.  It's a pure Perl implementation of the OpenPGP spec.

> DESCRIPTION
>
> Crypt::OpenPGP is a pure-Perl implementation of the [OpenPGP standard](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc4880.html). In addition to support for the standard itself, Crypt::OpenPGP claims compatibility with many other PGP implementations, both those that support the standard and those that preceded it.
>
> Crypt::OpenPGP provides signing/verification, encryption/decryption, keyring management, and key-pair generation; in short it should provide you with everything you need to PGP-enable yourself.

Here's an example of using it to verify a file:

```
my $pgp = Crypt::OpenPGP->new;

# Verify the detached signature $signature, which should be of the
# source file $file.
my $is_valid = $pgp->verify(
    Signature  => $signature,
    Files      => [ $file ],
);
```