# bash script checking if GPG signature is valid and belongs to a key

Tags: python, bash, gnupg

I am trying to write a bash script that checks if a given signature is valid or not. I have two possible outputs from:

```
$ gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/pubring.gpg  --verify file.tgz.sig file.tgz
```

WRONG

```
gpg: Signature made Tue 05 Apr 2011 11:01:19 CEST using RSA key ID E32804F0
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
```

RIGHT

```
gpg: Signature made Tue 05 Apr 2011 11:01:19 CEST using RSA key ID E32804F0
gpg: Good signature from "Test key <test@localhost>"
```

How I can detect if the checking was right without having to parse the result.

This question is similar to [Verify GPG file signature with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211655/verify-gpg-file-signature-with-perl) but II would like to do that in bash (or if very needed Python.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know the `gpg` command but does it return a different exit value for the "wrong" and "right" results?  The easiest way to check this after running the command would be:

```
echo $?
```

I would expect it to return 0 if everything is OK and something else if not.  So your bash script would look like:

```
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/pubring.gpg --verify file.tgz.sig file.tgz

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo All is well.
else
    echo Problem with signature.
fi
```

Comment: isn't that just the same as `gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/pubring.gpg --verify file.tgz.sig file.tgz && echo All is well || echo Problem with signature`? or w/ if: `if gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/pubring.gpg --verify file.tgz.sig file.tgz; then echo All is well ; else echo Problem with signature ; fi`

Comment: But who would expect a return value of `2`?? I ran `gpg --verify geckodriver-v0.32.2-linux64.tar.gz.asc ` for example which shows a valid RSA key. This seems to happen if you have not imported the public key. To do so, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55088831/3625433

Answer (score 1):

From the GnuPG man page:

> The program returns 0 if everything was fine, 1 if at least a signature was bad, and other error codes for fatal errors.

So you can use http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html to get the return code of `gpg`.