# Can't check signature: public key not found

Tags: encryption, cmd, pgp, gnupg

I try to decrypt file using following command:

```
gpg --output file.txt --decrypt file.pgp
```

File is decrypted successfully but i get an error:

> "gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found"

Any idea, why I get this error?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You get that error because you don't have the public key of the person who signed the message.

`gpg` should have given you a message containing the ID of the key that was used to sign it.  Obtain the public key from the person who encrypted the file and import it into your keyring (`gpg2 --import key.asc`); you should be able to verify the signature after that.

If the sender submitted its public key to a keyserver (for instance, https://pgp.mit.edu/), then you may be able to import the key directly from the keyserver:

```
gpg2 --keyserver https://pgp.mit.edu/ --search-keys <sender_name_or_address>
```

Comment: So why I could decrypt this file?

Comment: Because `gpg` doesn't require you to verify the signature in order to decrypt.

Comment: How do I import the public key once I have it?  E.g., how do I import the public keys at https://www.gnupg.org/signature_key.html

Comment: If you're using the command-line tools, copy the public key to a file, then use `gpg --import key.txt`.

Comment: This is happening to me with a file I signed myself. `gpg -k` lists my public key. Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't tell the whole story. With dsc I get the same message, and the key it mentions shows up after gpg --list-keys. There must be more to it, something with trust maybe.

Comment: I just had a similar issue and `--keyserver https://pgp.mit.edu/` didn't work for me, but `--keyserver hkps://pgp.mit.edu/` did.

Comment: I am new to PGP and I am a little confuse why is the public key needed. The file is signed with my public key, which I have provided to the other party, and I should be able to use my private key to decrypt it right?

Comment: @Sydney - The file is both signed and encrypted.  The encryption means that no one else can see the plaintext; decrypting it requires your private key.  The signature ensures that you can detect if anyone tampered with the file and can verify who sent it; verifying the signature requires the sender's public key.

Answer (score 41):

You need the public key in your gpg key ring.  To import the public key into your public keyring, place the public key block in a text file with a .gpg extension, and then issue the following command:

```
gpg --import <your-file>.gpg
```

The entity that encrypted the file should provide you with such a block.  For example, ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-keyring.gpg has the block for gnu.org.

For an even more in-depth explanation see
[Verifying files with GPG, without a .sig or .asc file?](https://superuser.com/questions/589524/verifying-files-with-gpg-without-a-sig-or-asc-file)

Comment: Is it possible to import a unknown public key automatically when verifying the signed message?

Comment: No idea, sorry.  On the surface it seems like you should be able to script pretty much anything to accomplish it "automatically."

Comment: @TJM it can be done see my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75621704/3625433)

Answer (score 35):

There is a similar problem.it is a tomcat digital signature.

```
$ gpg --verify apache-tomcat-9.0.16-windows-x64.zip.asc apache-tomcat-9.0.16-windows- 
x64.zip
gpg: Signature made 2019年02月 5日  0:32:50
gpg:                using RSA key A9C5DF4D22E99998D9875A5110C01C5A2F6059E7
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

but then I use the RSA key it provided to receive the public key to verify.

```
$ gpg --receive-keys A9C5DF4D22E99998D9875A5110C01C5A2F6059E7
gpg: key 10C01C5A2F6059E7: 38 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 10C01C5A2F6059E7: public key "Mark E D Thomas <markt@apache.org>" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

Then successfully.

```
$ gpg --verify apache-tomcat-9.0.16-windows-x64.zip.asc
gpg: assuming signed data in 'apache-tomcat-9.0.16-windows-x64.zip'
gpg: Signature made 2019年02月 5日  0:32:50
gpg:                using RSA key A9C5DF4D22E99998D9875A5110C01C5A2F6059E7
gpg: Good signature from "Mark E D Thomas <markt@apache.org>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: A9C5 DF4D 22E9 9998 D987  5A51 10C0 1C5A 2F60 59E7
```

Comment: I'm getting: `gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure`. Do I need to configure a key server?

Comment: To me helped the Ubuntu keyserver, which can also search keys: https://keyserver.ubuntu.com

Comment: Regarding `gpg --receive-keys A9C...`: without specifying a key server, it may default to a key server without a user ID ("`gpg: key ...9E7: new key but contains no user ID - skipped
`"), causing gpg to skip the import (see https://superuser.com/a/1485255/137881 ). If this happens, specify another key server which includes a user ID, e.g. `gpg --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A9C...`.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same message but my files are decrypted as expected. Please check in your destination path if you could see the output file file.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your signature is right, you can bypass `gpg` and test it manually:

Here I used `sha256sum` to validate my debian live ISO:

```sh
$% sha256sum debian-live-11.2.0-amd64-standard.iso | grep dd0dbffdb9c53ee8a35f869e95111a50e231a1800977dfd1604b64a0525709c9
dd0dbffdb9c53ee8a35f869e95111a50e231a1800977dfd1604b64a0525709c9  debian-live-11.2.0-amd64-standard.iso
```

Comment: And how did you know the hash was _supposed_ to be `dd0dbffdb9c53ee8a35f869e95111a50e231a1800977dfd1604b64a0525709c9`?

Comment: [It's listed on the website you can download your file from usually](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/SHA256SUMS), but there are issues with this approach alone. If an attacker compromises the server and fakes "trusted" SSL using a fake authority, this will be insecure. I searched for the sum and the filename to find mirrors such as [this one](http://ftp.twaren.net/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/bt-hybrid/SHA256SUMS) to verify the sum to be valid.

Comment: Nothing about this answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Debian, just try :

```
sudo apt-get install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring

sudo apt-key update

sudo apt-get update
```

Then, do your do :

```
gpg --output file.txt --decrypt file.pgp
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to import a public key in order to validate. In this case I downloaded the both files from open source.  Here my variables represent the respective filenames both `.tar.gz` and `tar.tz.asc`

```
# get the public key from asc file
rsa_key=$(gpg $driver_asc 2>&1 | grep RSA | awk '{print $5}')  

# import the public key
gpg --import $rsa

# verify valid signature
VERIFIED=$(gpg --verify $driver_asc $driver_filename 2>&1 | grep 'Good signature')

# handle results
if [[ $VERIFIED ]]; then
    echo "gpg key verified. Installing..."
    # do stuff with file, gunzip etc.
else
    echo "gpg key cannot be verified. Aborting installation"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced this while repo init,
I had to update the path variable in my linux machine and that resolved it.

PATH=~/bin:$PATH